# 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'DS_Filtering' and no extension method

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting the error below after enabling `SqlDataSource` filtering event on *default.aspx*.

> 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a
>   definition for 'DS_Filtering' and no
>   extension method

Am i missing anything?

Please help

Comment: can u post the code which u have tried so far.

Comment: Please post your form Design .

Answer (score 0):

Below might give you idea how this works, please check:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="FORM1" runat="server">

            <p>Show all employees with the following title:
            <asp:DropDownList
                id="DropDownList1"
                runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Sales Representative</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Sales Manager</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Vice President, Sales</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></p>

            <asp:SqlDataSource
                id="SqlDataSource1"
                runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnection %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Title FROM Employees"
                FilterExpression="Title='{0}'" OnFiltering="SqlDataSource1_Filtering">
                <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Title" ControlId="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
                </FilterParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource><br />

            <asp:GridView
                id="GridView1"
                runat="server"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <columns>
                    <asp:BoundField Visible="False" DataField="EmployeeID" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" />
                </columns>
            </asp:GridView>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server Side:

```
  protected void SqlDataSource1_Filtering(object sender, SqlDataSourceFilteringEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = e.ParameterValues[0].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I would like to replace the apostrophe on SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression. I tried this SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression.Replace("{0}", e.ParameterValues[0].ToString().Replace("'","''" );
but not working.

Comment: Use FilterExpression on Page_Load like:

SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "city='" +
     DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString().Replace("'","''" ); + "'";

Comment: doesn't work. I need to have Like %text% where text contains quote.

Comment: Use text = text.Replace("'","''" ); before applying.